# How can you wait until com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build() has completed

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I am using `com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel` to generate almost 1000 classes with associated JUnits for each one.

I also generate a JUnit Test Suite that executes the individual JUnit test cases.

To complete this code generation project i want to execute the JUnit test suite programmatically using `final Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);`.

The difficulty i am having is that the execution of the JUnit Test Suite is not synchronised to the code generation. I need to be able to detect when `com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build()` method has completed my code generation and only then execute the JUnit Test Suite.

How can I know when `com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build()` method completes?

Comment: How are you executing the JCodeModel code generation in relation to the JUnit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extend your class by JCodeModel and then override the build method:

```
@override
... build(){
super.build();
startTest();
}
```

then it should start after build function is finished.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However this doesnt resolve my issue as not only do i need to wait till all the generated classes are built, i also need them to have been compiled. I am executing this project within eclipse; its starting to look like i either need to refersh the eclipse project programatically (and wait or that to complete) or just give up and run the test suite manually

Comment: You could start the compiler manually ... JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());